# How to connect google sheet to Amazon QuickSight?

Tags: google-sheets, google-analytics, datasource, amazon-quicksight

I have Google Sheet which is schedule to run report daily and I have to create Dashboard in AWS QuickSight but I cant find any way to connect Google Sheet as a Data Source in QuickSight.
My google sheet's report is being populated from Google Analytics.

So, Is there any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

As per aws documentation, it seems we cannot directly integrate google sheets data as a datasource. The data either needs to be present in one of the Database or S3 or any relational data stores of aws.
We might need to make one of the following mechanisms :

1. Get the data in one of the relational database in aws through a script/cron and then pass it on to QuickSight for analysis.
2. Get the file in S3 through a script/cron and then pass it on to QuickSight for analysis.

Reference : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/quicksight/latest/user/supported-data-sources.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use a third party product to fill the gap:

https://skyvia.com/data-integration/analyze-google-sheets-with-quicksight

Or any of the other connector that link Analytics with Quicksight, there are plenty such as this:

https://www.dataddo.com/integration/google-analytics/amazon-aurora